# How to make a custom FreeBSD distribution

Tags: freebsd, distributions

I have been struggling for several hours on how to find a coherient guide on how to create your own BSD distribution based off of FreeBSD. I have looked at the GitHub repositories for pfsense, but I don't understand how it works. My goal is to create a custom distro that comes with a desktop environment and other desktop utilities already setup, etc... (not interested in PCBSD or any other similar solution)

I ran across the following [article](http://romana.now.ie/writing/customfreebsdiso.html), but it does not tell you how to install custom ports and customize the ISO, rather just compile the existing source. This [article](http://www.cyclecide.com/~rudy/example/custom-freebsd.html) is more in the direction I was aiming for, but it only sets up basic files and not ports. If I copy the binaries from ports, how will the system keep track of which programs need to be updated?

Furthermore, the documentation on the FreeBSD website is of not much help, it still does not cover installing custom ports.

Comment: Did you manage to get this in the end? I'm very interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first familiarize yourself with *FreeBSD* and building/getting ports. I really advise you to quietly read the [*FreeBSD* handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/), as *FreeBSD* is not Linux.

*FreeBSD* itself is a minimal coherent system (slightly server oriented, as having no X11 by default).

Then you can add ports, also called *packages* when in binary form. The [chapter 5 from the official FreeBSD handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html) is quite clear on how to get packages, how to get the ports tree (a set of files to build a package from source) or how to build form ports.

Here is a **small reminder** regarding ports:

1. get and/or sync your port tree:

   - get your port tree:

     ```
     svn checkout https://svn0.us-east.FreeBSD.org/ports/head /usr/ports
     ```

     You should use the subversion mirror site close to your location (see the [list here](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/svn-mirrors.html)).
   - sync your port tree:

     ```
     svn update /usr/ports
     ```
2. build the port you want to build (ex: *bash*, as *csh* is the default *FreeBSD* shell)

   ```
   cd /usr/ports/shells/bash
   make install && make clean
   ```

Then, once you have your base system with some ports you can try to make an ISO file.

**Note:**

The howtos you mentioned are targeting 5.x or 6.x. These can be used as guidelines, but it is strongly advised to read between the lines as some things have changed, particularly the way the *sources* are synchronized (no more unsecured `cvsup`, `svn` is now used for instance).

*pfSense* is not based on a full *FreeBSD*, but on its extremely minimal form called [*NanoBSD*](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/nanobsd/) which is targetting more embedded systems than desktop setup.

**To know more**:

- [FreeBSD handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/)
- [FreeBSD: packages and ports](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html)

Comment: So if I just install the base system, then the ports I want as specified I can just use like "dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/mydistro.iso" kinda thing and that will boot with an installer and everything?

Comment: As soon as you keep all the things in `/` (no other partition), then there is good chance you got something almost working (you might still need to fix a few conf files).

Comment: Beware. An ISO fs requires some other things to properly boot. You should use the `mkisofs` (or another ISO making tool), as suggested by the link you gave.